# Mock function with NUnit?

Tags: c#, .net, function, mocking, nunit

Is it possible to mock a function call with NUnit? I know the standard answer here is extract an interface and use dependency injection, but I want to know if it is even possible to not do that and just mock a function call.

Comment: In java, with PowerMock, you can do that. But when everybody is using PowerMock for unit testing in the project, no one care about the design because you can almost mock everything, so the unit tests ended up as a mess, that happened to one of my projects.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of what you want to mock?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, without an interface etc.

Without interfacing, you might need to resort to Microsoft Fakes (Shims) to mock a method call as is. (and it can get dicey with generation of Fakes assemblies)

Fakes works well when you have a method like

```
public DateTime GetCurrentUtcDate()
{
 return DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

and you want to run an unit test involving code which calls this method. we don't generally think of interfaces/DI for such methods.. Fakes comes handy for such cases.